# How to make a model recognize new things

Tags: yolov5

For example, I have a trained model: myYolo.pt, assuming it can already recognize cats and dogs, how can I make myYolo.pt model recognize a new thing: squirrel

list：

1. myYolo.pt can only recognize cats and dogs
2. There is no data about cats and dogs at this time, so I cannot retrain myYolo.pt from scratch、
3. At this time, there are only relevant picture data of squirrels
4. Use the myYolo.pt model to recognize new things on the basis of the original: squirrels. without training the entire model from scratch

Thanks for your help, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Assuming you have a [one-hot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot) output, you can't; how would you figure out if the result was squirrel? If your model already allows it to output squirrel as a result but it simply doesn't know about squirrels, then just more training should suffice, this time without ignoring the rodent kind.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993575/yolov5-custom-retraining?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible. If you have a Yolov5 model that recognize certain objects, load it and start a new training with a new single object, the model will adjust the weights for that single object in your dataset. Little at a time, the weights obtained in your first training will adapt to the new single class dataset. This will make it impossible to detect the previous classes.

Some type of architectures, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68993575/yolov5-custom-retraining?rq=1) can handle this in a better way. But it is not the case of Yolo architectures.

That is why you need to have all the classes you want to detect in a single dataset and retrain.